# Merge rows residing inside json array based on certain Keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, merge, group-by

Looking for a solution to a problem:

Need to merge the following array, such that final output has only one row corresponding to each unique combination of category and subcategory, rest of the fields(topic and personal), merged into one single array:

Input:

```
[
   {
      "category":"cat2",
      "subcategory":"b",
      "personal":[
         "inclsn2"
      ],
      "topic":[
         "topic1",
         "topic3"
      ]
   },
   {
      "category":"cat1",
      "subcategory":"a",
      "personal":[
         "inclsn2"
      ],
      "topic":[
         "topic4"
      ]
   },
   {
      "category":"cat2",
      "subcategory":"b",
      "personal":[
         "inclsn2"
      ],
      "topic":[
         "topic5",
         "topic2"
      ]
   },
   {
      "category":"cat2",
      "subcategory":"b",
      "personal":[
         "inclsn2"
      ],
      "topic":[
         "topic1",
         "topic2"
      ]
   },
   {
      "category":"cat2",
      "subcategory":"b",
      "personal":[
         "inclsn2"
      ],
      "topic":[
         "topic1",
         "topic2"
      ]
   },
   {
      "category":"cat1",
      "subcategory":"a",
      "personal":[
         "inclsn2"
      ],
      "topic":[
         "topic1",
         "topic2"
      ]
   },
   {
      "category":"cat1",
      "subcategory":"a",
      "personal":[
         "inclsn2"
      ],
      "topic":[
         "topic1",
         "topic2"
      ]
   },
   {
      "category":"cat3",
      "subcategory":"c",
      "personal":[
         "inclsn3"
      ],
      "topic":[
         "topic1",
         "topic2"
      ]
   },
   {
      "category":"cat1",
      "subcategory":"a",
      "personal":[
         "inclsn2"
      ],
      "topic":[
         "topic1",
         "topic2"
      ]
   },
   {
      "category":"cat1",
      "subcategory":"a",
      "personal":null,
      "topic":[
         "topic6"
      ]
   }
]
```

Expected output:

```
[{"category": "cat2", "subcategory": "b", "personal": ["inclsn2"], "topic": ["topic2","topic5","topic4","topic1"]},
{"category": "cat1", "subcategory": "a", "personal": ["inclsn2"], "topic": ["topic6","topic2","topic4","topic1"]},
{"category": "cat3", "subcategory": "c", "personal": ["inclsn3"], "topic": ["topic1","topic2"]}]
```

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem would be to filter the array with a condition of not seeing the category/subcategory combination before. You can use an object whose keys would be some combination of category/subcategory (e.g. concatenated with some delimiter) and see if that object has a given key.

You can do it with something like this:

```js
const input = [] // your array here

const d = '\t';
const merge = (a, c = {}) => a.filter((e, f, k) =>
              (k = e.category + d + e.subcategory, f = c[k], c[k] = 1, !f));

console.log(merge(input));
```

Make sure to set `d` to some string that will never be a part of a real category or subcategory name - here it is a tab character but you can set it to anything else.

Output for your array:

```js
[ { category: 'cat2',
    subcategory: 'b',
    personal: [ 'inclsn2' ],
    topic: [ 'topic1', 'topic3' ] },
  { category: 'cat1',
    subcategory: 'a',
    personal: [ 'inclsn2' ],
    topic: [ 'topic4' ] },
  { category: 'cat3',
    subcategory: 'c',
    personal: [ 'inclsn3' ],
    topic: [ 'topic1', 'topic2' ] } ]
```

If you are using Lodash then you can simplify your `merge()` function even further:

```js
const _ = require('lodash');

const d = '\t';
const merge = a => _.uniqBy(a, e => e.category + d + e.subcategory);

console.log(merge(input));
```